# VNC Remote access like a graphical console

Tags: vnc, console, username

I've installed vncserver already.
Now, I need access to the desktop by typing a username and password.

*Is this possible?*

Comment: It's possible, just use a vnc client. You can remotely access your machine using remote X.org too.

Answer (score 0):

From your Ubuntu client machine:

- go to the dash:

  [image]
- type `remmina`
- open the application,
- click the little green <kbd>+</kbd>
- change the name "Quick Connect" to `WhatEverYouWant`.
- click on protocol and choose `VNC - Virtual Network Computing`
- click on <kbd>Server</kbd> and add the IP address
- optional: add the username and password there
- click <kbd>Save</kbd>

Double-click `WhatEverYouWant`

#### Done!  ;-)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)